# Symmetric Riemann-Stieltjes Integrals

Tags: symmetry, stieltjes-integral

**Background:**

I recently had to compute the following Riemann-Stieltjes integral for a homework assignment:

$$\int_\limits{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos(x)d|\sin(x)|=0$$

It occured to me that this looks similar to the symmetric Riemann integral 
$$\int_\limits{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos(x)dx=2\int_\limits{0}^{\pi}\cos(x)dx=0$$
which we know is 0 without computing because $\cos(x)$ is symmetric about $\pi/2$.

**Question:**

Is there any theory to know the answer (and to identify) symmetric Riemann-Stieltjes integrals?

Comment: Ideally you'd like to use the fact that $|\sin x|$ is smooth on intervals where it is non-zero so that you can use the identity $\int f(x) d\alpha(x) = \int f(x)\alpha'(x) dx$. Does that help?

Comment: Ahh. Yes. So then you simply apply the normal symmetric theory to the new integral, where you consider the product $f(x)\alpha'(x)$?

Comment: That is correct.